# How to do a disappearing elements for right side this same as it's working for left side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make the overflow to the right hidden yet not working.

Basically, I want the items to be hidden when animated to the right just like animated to the left.

```js
$("#left_btn").click(function(){
       $("#container").animate({
                left: '+=200px'
            }, 'slow');        
    })
    
    
        $("#right_btn").click(function(){
        $("#container").animate({
                left: '-=200px'
            }, 'slow'); 
    })
```

```css
#container{

  position: absolute;
  left: 180px;
  bottom: 150px;
  top: 40px;
   
}



#image_one_div {
  position: relative;
  float:left;

}

#image_two_div {
  position: relative;
  float:left;

}
#image_three_div{
  position: relative;
  float:left;

}


#image_one_div, #image_two_div, #image_three_div {
  
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-left: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="right_btn">
left
</button>
<button id="left_btn">
right
</button>


<div id="container">



<div id="image_one_div">

</div>

<div id="image_two_div">

</div>
<div id="image_three_div">


</div>

</div>
```

Right now animations to the right make the items to go above one another. How can this issue be solved? I would appreciate any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `overflow: hidden;` for `#container` dom element and you have to set a `right` of `#container` by proper value for you. It has to work well.

```js
$("#left_btn").click(function(){
       $("#container").animate({
                left: '+=200px'
            }, 'slow');        
    })
    
    
        $("#right_btn").click(function(){
        $("#container").animate({
                left: '-=200px'
            }, 'slow'); 
    })
```

```css
#container{

  position: absolute;
  left: 180px;
  right: 180px;
  bottom: 150px;
  top: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
}



#image_one_div {
  position: relative;
  float:left;

}

#image_two_div {
  position: relative;
  float:left;

}
#image_three_div{
  position: relative;
  float:left;

}


#image_one_div, #image_two_div, #image_three_div {
  
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-left: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="right_btn">
left
</button>
<button id="left_btn">
right
</button>


<div id="container">



<div id="image_one_div">

</div>

<div id="image_two_div">

</div>
<div id="image_three_div">


</div>

</div>
```

Comment: thanks that work on this case but when I applied the same method on my local project it didn't work.

Comment: you have to set a right for #container element too. I changed my answer. Check it out.